# Paired T- test assumption about the underlying variance

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the assumption for paired t-test underlying variance?

I know that the difference between paired t-test and independent t-test is that in a paired t-test, samples need to be correlated. But does it mean that the variance on the samples need to be similar (same)?

If the variance are different, would the test still hold?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is from the same group (for example, a before weight and an after weight from the same individuals) then a paired t-test is appropriate. If the data is from different groups (for example, comparing men's weight with women's weights) then an independent t-test is appropriate. You can compare the *ratio of variances* in two groups and if this ratio is greater than 2, then the variances are usually unequal. If the variance is equal (meaning ratio is less than 2) then you can perform the t-test but make sure it is "pooled" but if the variance is not equal then "unpooled". This pooled vs unpooled is a feature you can edit in performing a t-test in a graphing calculator or other computer software and does evaluate the groups differently, I would suggest looking more into it

Comment: Thank you, what would happen if I use the paired t-test on samples with different variance (or ratio >2)?

Comment: actually a paired t-test is not subject to  variation because the paired observations are dependent. Also, a paired t-test does not require both samples to have equaal variances. Pretty nice right? Now equal or unequal variation is important when samples are NOT dependent

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part where paired t-test is not subject to same variance? I was under the impression that they have to be the same.

Comment: A paired t-test is not subject to the same variance because of the fact that the samples are dependent. There is no variation occurring from independent samples. For example, there may be variation occurring in paired data because of a difference due to a weight loss pill, but not variation due to actual differences in the  samples themselves. I'm sorry if this didn't help much. I would encourage you to ask this in class or to your professor, I'm sure s/he can explain better than me, but that is my understanding of why paired t-test is not subject to unequal variances.

Comment: man I wish I was still in school, I graduated already, doing this for some research at work.

Comment: @Brandon: The rough rule about ratio of 2:1 in sample variances may be helpful in a particular situation, but it is certainly not OK in general. In gen'l, one uses an F-test to check whether sample variances are significantly different (or have ratio signif different from 1). The size of the samples plays a huge role in determining what ratio of differences in sample variances is significant. For example, if both samples are of size 10 then the ratio of the larger variance to the smaller would have to exceed 4, for significance at 5%. For two samples of size 40, a ratio exceeding 1.9 suffices.

Comment: @AllieLovesMath: Usually, paired data result in positive correlation. The paired t test exploits this to achieve higher power (better ability to detect true differences in pop means). However, to be sure of correct inferences, you should use a paired test whenever data are paired. Significantly positive correlation is _not a required assumption_ for a paired test. However, independence (thus 0 population correlation) _is_ a required assumption for an (independent) 2-sample test.

Comment: @BruceET good to know. I'm glad people like you whom have more knowledge can help give me bits and pieces of useful advice, and to others also. Just finishing my bachelors in stats and I know I have far more to learn.

Comment: @AllieLovesMath, About equality of var's: In a 2-sample situation, a _pooled_ t test assumes = var's, but a _Welch_ (separate variances) t test doesn't. In practice, it;s best to do Welch test unless you have strong prior knowledge that var's are equal. (That is why the Welch test is the default test in most stat software; if you _insist_ on the pooled test, you have to explicitly request it.) // In paired tests it may happen that the var's are $\ne$, but it doesn't affect test validity. [In a drug trial, Var(After) may exceed Var(Before) because Var(After) includes pop var + drug effect var.]

Comment: Of course, we _all_ have a lot to learn. The goal in giving useful answers is to try to separate what we know for sure to be true from what we only suspect may be true. And I suppose we all have to work on that too.